# Media Queries on Bootstrap Page not applied

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm on my first Bootstrap page and want to apply some changes only for Tablet portrait and smartphones.
Somehow, all the changes I made within the media queries are not applied to the page (e.g. the red border as test). Does anybody have an idea why?

http://codepen.io/herbigt/pen/KcGro

```
@media (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 481px) {
.pull-left, .pull-right{
    margin:0 auto; 
    display:block; 
    float: none !important;

}
.standard-element {
    border: 1 px solid red;
}
}

/* Mobile */
@media (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 0px) {
.pull-left, .pull-right{
    margin:0 auto; 
    display:block; 
    float: none !important;
}
.standard-element {
    border: 1 px solid red;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

border: 1 px solid red is wrong it must be border: 1px solid red. The blank between 1 and px may cause the problem.

Comment: Yeah, the border is now applied. So the queries are recognized, but the centering of the images is not - Do you have an idea why?

Comment: Centering image vertically on the red bordered div or centering the red bordered div horizontally on the screen?

Comment: Centering the image horizontally within the red bordered div (for portrait tablets and smartphones). I had to use .pull-right and .pull-left to position them accordingly on the desktop layout.

Comment: But then it's the for all screens centered. How could I enable this behaviour only for certain media queries?

Comment: bootstrap provides xs for extra small devices md for medium devices and lg for large devices. For each device you can add different scale. For more information you can check here: http://getbootstrap.com/css - see grid systems

Answer (score 0):

Try this queries:

```
/* Large desktops and laptops */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {

}

/* Portrait tablets and medium desktops */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

}

/* Portrait tablets and small desktops */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

}

/* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */
@media (max-width: 767px) {

}

/* Landscape phones and smaller */
@media (max-width: 480px) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try sth like this. You need to surround image tag with a new container div.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6"></div>
     <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6">
        <img style="border:1px solid red" src="" class="img-responsive pull-right" alt="">
     </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6"></div>
 </div>
```